# React Native Invalid Hook Call Warning

Tags: react-native

Cuando yo coloco lo siguiente en mi código:

```
    const [showText, setShowText] = useState(true);
    const onPress = () => {
      setShowText(!showText);
    };
```

Aparece el siguiente error:

> [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

¿Alguna ayuda para solucionar mi problema? ¿Cuál es mi error? ¿Hay alguna alternativa?

Yo estoy tratando de ocultar un elemento con:

```
const texto = showText ? <ViroText width={4} height={0.5} text="VISIBLE" style={styles.TextStyle} />  : <ViroText width={4} height={0.5} text="NO VISIBLE" style={styles.TextStyle} />; 

return (    
...Button... 
onPress={onPress}

{texto}
```

Answer (score 0):

esto se puede deber a que tienes dos modulos de react en el dom de node,al import el hook sale el warning ya que apunta a varios módulos a la vez,para ver si tienes mas de uno lanza el siguiente comando en node:

```
npm ls react
```

Con esto te saldrá si existe más de un modulo react,una vez confirmes elimina uno de estos en el dom y se arreglará el warning.
Por si acaso te dejo el link de donde saqué la info:
https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react
Espero que te sirva de ayuda.